# Parsing Json extracting key value python

Tags: python, json, api, rest

Hi guys I am trying to extract the same key but with different values over a long JSON response, but i keep getting :

`KeyError: 'id'`

Not sure what i am doing wrong, but i am accessing it using REST API:
This is what i have as a script :

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import json
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

def countries():
    data = requests.get("https://10.24.21.4:8543/api/netim/v1/countries/", verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "admin"))
    rep = data.json()
    for cid in rep:
        cid = rep["id"]
        print(cid)
countries()
```

The response is rather long, but it is like this, you will see "id", and i need the respective values :

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Afghanistan",
            "displayName": "Afghanistan",
            "meta": {
                "type": "COUNTRY"
            },
            "id": "AF",
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "path": "/api/netim/v1/countries/AF"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Albania",
            "displayName": "Albania",
            "meta": {
                "type": "COUNTRY"
            },
            "id": "AL",
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "path": "/api/netim/v1/countries/AL"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Algeria",
            "displayName": "Algeria",
            "meta": {
                "type": "COUNTRY"
            },
            "id": "DZ",
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "path": "/api/netim/v1/countries/DZ"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "American Samoa",
            "displayName": "American Samoa",
            "meta": {
                "type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your functions a little, You should now be able to get all teh IDs from the JSON response. I suggest you look into teh basics of Dictionaries and Lists in Python

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import json
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

def countries():
    data = requests.get("https://10.24.21.4:8543/api/netim/v1/countries/", verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "admin"))
    rep = data.json()
    return [elem.get("id","") for elem in rep['items']]

countries()
```

Update:
If you wish to extract the value of the "path" key and simultaneously the value of the "id" key, You would need a list of dictionaries where every dictionary corresponds to a single record from the json.

the modified function is as follows:

```
def countries():
    data = requests.get("https://10.24.21.4:8543/api/netim/v1/countries/", verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "admin"))
    rep = data.json()
    return [{"id":elem.get("id",""),"path":elem["links"]["self"]["path"]} for elem in rep['items']]
```

the `get()` returns a default value in case the key is absent in the dictionary. The function, new as well as the previous one, would not fail in case the values were not returned in the JSON response for the **id** and **path** keys

If you are sure that the value of `links` will always be available you can use the above function directly else you will have to write a custom function that would parse the key `links` and return an empty string if it is empty in the json

Comment: Hi thank you very much, i am not a programmer myself, just working on some stuff for work. QQ, and how could i get the key "path" ? apologies

Comment: Do you need both the ID and value of Path in the result set?

Comment: I have made changes to the answer.Please have a look at it

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, this was extremely helpful ! i will follow you advice and l will look in to the basics of dictionaries and list, thank you once more!

Answer (score 0):

The response is not an array, it's a dictionary.
You want the "items" element of that dictionary:

```
for cid in rep['items']:
```